# Adding `params` and `session` and `env` to Object

Tags: ruby, rack

In a gem I'm writing I am trying to add the rack methods `params`, `session`, and `env` to `Object` so that they can be accessed and modified by the user of the gem. I have tried using `Object.instance_variable_set` and `Object.instance_variable_get` to add the variables to `Object` and then set them again by retrieving them from `Object`. I have been using the `Rack::Request.new(env)` interface to do this. The only problem is that it seems to be impossible to set `params` and `session` through this object. This has led be to believe that I am doing something very wrong. How can I set `params` and `session` through `Rack::Request`? Please also let me know if what I'm doing is bad practice or if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: This is old, but interesting. If you're still out there @thesecretmaster can you let us know what solution you ended up using?

Comment: Yeah, I'll try to remember this weekend. Feel free to ping me again if I don't get back to you.