# Add variable to main

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

For a gem I'm working on I need to add a variable to main, preferably a local variable, but instance works as well. I've been trying to use `Object.instance_variable_set`, but have made no progress that way. How can I accomplish this?

**Clarification**

I need to set the instance variable from a module within `main`.

Here is my situation:

```
module MyGem::Submodule
    def self.add_variable_to_main
        Object.instance_variable_set(:@var,"value")
    end
    def self.recieve_variable_from_main
        Object.instance_variable_get(:@var)
    end
    def self.store_block
        @@block=&block
    end
    def self.call_block
        add_variable_to_main
        @@block.call
        puts recieve_variable_from_main
    end
end

class Object
    include MyGem::Submodule
end

store_block do
    @var = "Var is #{@var}"
end

call_block
```

I also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38675366/adding-params-and-session-and-env-to-object) about the same problem, it has additional details.

Comment: `main` is the `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` context are you really sure this is where you want to add this? Please explain a use case for this that would not be as easily handled by a global object or a top level constant. A gem should be an encapsulated library and mutating the top level could have unintended outcomes.

Comment: @engineersmnky In my gem I need to set a variable accessable in main, but doing it though an object would work just as well. Could you write an answer explaining the disadvantages and good alternatives?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are hoping to achieve? I think you misunderstand the concept of `main`

Comment: @engineersmnky I've added an example, thanks for bearing with me, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How will this variable change or wont it? How will this variable be used? Like I said a gem is meant to be encapsulated so we need to understand why this is needed. If the variable will never change you can use a constant like `::VARIABLE` the leading colons will put it in the TOP LEVEL namespace. If it will change you could possibly use a global like `$variable` leading `$` will make this globally available. Without understanding the concepts behind why you need this (which I am uncertain you actually do) I can't form an answer that would be more appropriate than the ones listed below.

Comment: Please note either one of these solutions breaks the encapsulation of the gem and could potentially cause collisions when the gem is included in a project that defines a variable by the same name in the same context.

Comment: @engineersmnky Here is a complete example. Also, the linked question provides even more context for "Why???".

Comment: This is not a good solution and will not solve the question asked. These variables will not have any impact on `Rack` as those will handled inside of rack and will not propogate down from `Object` I would recommend looking into a completely different solution. I think your focus on `main` is based on testing in irb. To solve this would require you to modify the Rack library itself.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for your help, I'm going to look into better solutions. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @engineersmnky I think I'm going to try using classes and extending Rack::Request

Answer (score 4):

`main` is an object, objects can't have local variables. Local variables belong to lexical scopes, not objects.

You can simply assign to an instance variable in the context of `main`:

```
@ivar = 42
```

Now `main` has an instance variable `@ivar` with a value of `42`.

[`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) works the same way:

```
instance_variable_set(:@ivar, 42)
```

If you are not within the context of `main`, you can access the top-level [`Binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html) via the global constant [`TOPLEVEL_BINDING`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#TOPLEVEL_BINDING), and the `main` object itself via [`TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Binding.html#method-i-receiver), since `main` is the implicit receiver, i.e. `self` at the top-level:

```
module Foo
  TOPLEVEL_BINDING.receiver.instance_variable_set(:@ivar, 42)
end

@ivar # => 42
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, because my issue is that I have to set it from a module in `main`, because this is a gem and I need to set a variable behind the scenes for the user, so this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think that would work, I'm just refraining from accepting an answer until I do a bit more research myself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a constant `TOPLEVEL_BINDING` that stores the binding of `main`. You can set instance variables to `main` from anywhere with that binding.

```
module Foo
  TOPLEVEL_BINDING.eval '@foo = :bar'
end

@foo  #=> :bar
```