# How can I use the sinatra http verb methods?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, sinatra

I know how the [http verb methods](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1398) (get, post, puts, etc.) are defined. What I don't understand is how can I use the http verb methods in my app file, even though they are not added to `Object`?

I understand how they are used, I'm just trying to understand how sinatra works under the hood.

Comment: Official documentation has everything you need. http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html
Routes section contains examples with different http verbs.

Comment: @SunnyMagadan I've clarified my question

Answer (score 1):

It extends global context (`Object`) with a `Sinatra::Delegator` module which delegates appropriate methods for routes definition to Sinatra Application.
https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/4797c022c96f7e023a365d5852c89fde0e08fa3e/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L31

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/4797c022c96f7e023a365d5852c89fde0e08fa3e/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1925-L1949

Here is a good example of building sinatra-like application: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-build-a-sinatra
Above tutorial uses the same delegation approach as Sinatra.

Comment: So the http verb methods are part of a class that main extends?

Comment: Also, thanks for the tutorial link. I'd actually already completed it and had some questions about it (if you'd be interested in answering) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357195/how-does-sinatra-start-the-server).

Comment: Yes. These http verbs methods are defined at Sinatra::Application and Sinatra::Delegator just allows to use them from global context by injecting them into Object.